# Unit Testing and Integration Testing demarcation in a maven database layer module

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, maven, model, integration-testing

I believe i've been making the same mistake when it comes to the kind of test i have to write.
we have differents maven modules in our application, and there is one called `model` which have all the pojos, daos, all the hibernate stuffs.It only does CRUD operations and doesn't know about all the other modules.

Well after writing the DAOs i feel like have a test that actually proves that objects are being persisted and deleted etc.That in fact turns out to be an integration test instead from what i've read so far.

Doing unit test with mocks also on the other doesn't make sense to me as far it concerns CRUD operations.

Now i've kind of divided in the stance to take when it comes to testing that module.

What's the best practice here? what is it done in a proper project?

thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of approaches I can think of.

One would be to just stick to what you have been doing whether it's called integration or unit test. Usually this type of modules have very little business logic to test, so CRUD operations is the only testable thing. If you have easily accessible database and design your tests to clean after themselves, it would be just fine. Better yet, if you have database that you can just dump before beginning of test.

Other approach many places use, is to use in memory database for testing (Hypersonic, for example). But since you use different database you are not testing exactly the product that you build. Yet it will validate your Hibernate mapping and queries (that are not target db specific), which, perhaps is most important testable aspect of your module.

Comment: hello, thanks for the response.I've been using hsqldb in file mode and mysql.the target database being mysql.I'm using script so in the context i switch the properties file for the db i want tested (mysql.jdbc.properties/msyql.hibernate.properties and the same for hsql). So i guess i just have stick to that.Thanks